# Array relationship and juxtaposition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am making a static html landing page for musicians to have a quick reference for what is known as negative harmony in music. 
I have the idea that I can auto generate the negative harmony 'chords' for each key signature based on the user clicking on the key they want to play in.

E.G. click on A major and display the related negative harmony chords.

For example:

user wants to play in the key of C Major (they click 'C major button') and wants negative harmony related to it, the arrays will look like:

```
['C-I', 'd-ii', 'e-iii', 'F-IV' 'G-V' 'a-vi' 'b-vii°'] - (C major)
['g-v', 'f-iv', 'Eb-I', 'd-v°', 'c-i', 'Bb-V', 'Ab-IV'] - (C minor)
```

I will construct every array for each key signature, what I need them to do is have this relationship, best explained through this image:

[image]

So basically if they click on "C Major", I will need to map an array with one arrays relationship moving (forward) through *index* 0...6 relating to element in other index (backward) from 6...0

Both of which at this point I will append to the DOM in a similar fashion to the image with color correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package for that: `negative-harmony` on NPM. If you want to do it from scratch, you don't need to write out arrays for each mode in every key. [This code](https://github.com/mauriciocarbajal/negative-harmony/blob/master/find-opposite-chord.js), for example, is succinct and handles the problem pretty well, though if you choose reuse it you would need to write out *interval* mappings for each mode and add that to the logic. If you're dead set on using mappings of hand-crafted arrays of notes, the opposite-finding logic in the above link would also work great for you.

Comment: Thank you @Zac Anger, this will be helpful in what I am trying to achieve. As for interval mappings, I don't see where I will pass them into any of the functions, can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah sorry, what I meant by that was that if your input takes chords, you'll need to map out what those chords mean for each mode, because (for example) the 6th chord in one mode may have very different intervals from the 6th in another mode. Then those intervals would have to be passed down to `getOppositeIndex` through the other functions, because the code in that repo looks like it assumes Ionian (I think). And as a side note, one or more of the [tonal](https://github.com/tonaljs/tonal/tree/main/packages) packages could make that a lot simpler.